# Angularjs filter is not working with methods

Tags: angularjs, html

I am retrieving data from SQL table and displaying it in a html table, and when i click on a row in this table the values are displayed in input texts to EDIT/DELETE them. 
I made an Angular filter but it is not working and the input texts are disabled. It was working before applying the method "selectedMember" to clear input texts.
Any idea how to solve this problem , thanks in advance

The HTML is :

```
<body ng-app="ContractT" ng-controller="crudController">
   <br /><br />
   <form >
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Hide" />Hide <input type="button" value="Clear" ng-click="resetform()" />
      <input type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="save()"/> <input type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="delete(selectedMember.sys_key)" />
      <fieldset>
         <legend>Contract Type</legend>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Code</td>
               <td><input type="text" size="10" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" title="Alphnumeric" required autofocus ng-model="selectedMember.Code.Staff_Type_Code">
                  <input type="text" size="10" hidden ng-model="selectedMember.sys_key" /> 
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Latin Description</td>
               <td><input type="text" required size="35" ng-model="selectedMember.Latin.L_Desc"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Local Description</td>
               <td><input type="text" required size="35" ng-model="selectedMember.Local.A_Desc"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>No. Of Houres Per Day</td>
               <td><input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Please enter numbers only" size="10" maxlength="2" ng-model="selectedMember.Hours_Day"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>No. Of Days Per Week(s)</td>
               <td><input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Please enter numbers only" size="10" maxlength="2" ng-model="selectedMember.Days_Week"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>End Of Contract By</td>
               <td>
                  <select>
                     <option ng-model="Age">Age</option>
                     <option ng-model="NYears">Number Of Years in Service</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Number</td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Please enter numbers only" size="10" maxlength="2" ng-model="selectedMember.Num_EndWork">
                  <select>
                     <option ng-model="Months">Months</option>
                     <option ng-model="Years">Years</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </fieldset>
      <br />
      <table border="1" ng-hide="Hide">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <!--<th>syskey</th>-->
               <th>Code</th>
               <th>Latin Description</th>
               <th>Local Description</th>
               <th>Hours_Day</th>
               <th>Days_Week</th>
               <th>Num_EndWork</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="c in Contracts | filter:Code | filter:Latin | filter:Local ">
               <td style="display:none;"><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.sys_key}}</a></td>
               <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Staff_Type_Code}}</a></td>
               <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.L_Desc}}</a></td>
               <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.A_Desc}}</a></td>
               <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Hours_Day}}</a></td>
               <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Days_Week}}</a></td>
               <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Num_EndWork}}</a></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </form>
</body>
```

The Controller is :

```
    contractT.controller('crudController', function($scope, crudService) {

        loadrecords();

        function loadrecords() {
            crudService.getContracts().then(function(response) {
                $scope.Contracts = (response.data);
                console.log($scope.Contracts);
            });
        }

        $scope.resetform = function() {
            $scope.selectedMember = {};
            //$scope.selectedMember = {};
            //$scope.Local = {};
            //$scope.Nhd = null;
            //$scope.Ndw = null;
            //$scope.Num = null;
        }

        $scope.selectedMember = {
            Code: "",
            sys_key: "",
            Latin: "",
            Local: "",
            Hours_Day: "",
            Days_Week: "",
            Num_EndWork: ""
        }

        $scope.showInEdit = function(member) {
            $scope.selectedMember = member;
            $scope.selectedMember.Code = member;
            $scope.selectedMember.Latin = member;
            $scope.selectedMember.Local = member;
            //$scope.selectedMember.Hours_Day = member;
            //$scope.selectedMember.Days_Week = member;
            //$scope.selectedMember.Num_EndWork = member;
        }

        $scope.delete = function(sys_key) {
            if ($scope.selectedMember.sys_key = {})
                alert("Please select a valid values");

            else if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete?")) {
                var promiseGetSingle = crudService.delete(sys_key);

                promiseGetSingle.then(function(pl) {
                        $scope.OneContract = pl.data;

                        $scope.selectedMember = {};
                        alert("Deleted Successfully");
                        loadrecords();
                    },
                    function(errorPl) {
                        console.log('failure deleteing Contract', errorPl);
                    });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: $scope.showInEdit = function (member)
{
    $scope.selectedMember = member;
}

Comment: problem is here check properly first your json object and comming from db

Comment: thanks for replying, but it was working very well before adding the selectedMember.

Comment: edit your question and provide your json object in it. It will be more helpfull

Comment: I am new in angular, I am using a web API method that return data in json format, do you mean the angular service or the data sent from API, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in Contracts | filter:selectedMember.Code | filter:selectedMember.Latin | filter:selectedMember.Local ">
```